# Method 'showBottomSheet' cannot be called on 'ScaffoldState?' because it is potentially null

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, dart-null-safety, null-safety

Hello I'm getting this error when I tried to run the code

```
lib/layout/home_layout.dart:54:36: Error: Method 'showBottomSheet' cannot be called on 'ScaffoldState?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'ScaffoldState' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
          scaffoldKey.currentState.showBottomSheet(
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I have a variable that I have defined:

```
 var scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

Here I am trying to build a bottomsheet when clicking on the floatingactionbutton

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      scaffoldKey.currentState.showBottomSheet(
              (context) => Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 120.0,
                color: Colors.red
              ),
      );
    },
    child: const Icon(
        Icons.add
    ),
  ),
```

***Kindly, can someone tell me where I am going wrong?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is, as you might have already figured out, that flutter doesn't know if the current state variable is null, there are some situations in which it is null, and because of that, it will not let you call it, here is the obvious solution:

```
if (scaffoldKey.currentState != null) {
  scaffoldKey.currentState!.showBottomSheet(...);
}
```

Note the `!` after `currentState`, when you place `!` after a potentially null value, you are telling flutter, "trust me, this value is not null" which means it will throw an error if it is null, but it won't complain otherwise.

A, perhaps better solution is doing what your error code suggests:

> Method 'showBottomSheet' cannot be called on 'ScaffoldState?' because it is potentially null.
> Try calling using **?.** instead.
> scaffoldKey.currentState.showBottomSheet(

Like this:

```
scaffoldKey.currentState?.showBottomSheet(...);
```

When using `?.` you are conditionally calling a method or a member variable on a potentially null value

So what the above line says is, "if `currentState` is not null, call it's `showBottomSheet` method, otherwise, do nothing".

Answer (score 0):

I know this example from Abdullah Mansour's The Complete 2022 Flutter & Dart Development Course [Arabic] in Udemy.
[The answer of h8moss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70042887/18837598) is very good and complain a part of the null safety concept in flutter and especially in your case but it didn't help you to show the **BottomSheet** as I think.
So,  I figured out that it's actually the **GlobalKey** that returns a null state. The question is why?

You need to pass the key into the scaffold widget, then the context and state will be set.

```
class _HomeLayoutState extends State<HomeLayout> { GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey(); //so we can call snackbar from anywhere
```

...

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    key: scaffoldKey, //set state and context
```

finally, Note the **!** after currentState, when you place **!** after a potentially null value, you are telling flutter, **"trust me, this value is not null"**:

```
scaffoldKey.currentState!.showBottomSheet(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you need done in 2023

```
 showModalBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context)=> ExpenseCategoryBottomSheet(),
                );
```